# PHP Directory download

Tags: php, apache, debian

I'm looking for a best practice method to deserve directory content on download to a user.

Currently I give to users, two techniques :
- One by One download using PHP and XSendFile for Apache to better deserve files
- A stack for "zipping" a directory temporary (24hours) and download a zip containing a whole directory with the directory hierarchy.

But I'm looking for a better support on a whole directory download in PHP (or other). Do you have any kind of idea to get lower CPU/memory cost and deserve a whole directory faster ?

(The only restriction is to be on server side and the user is navigating through a web browser)

Thank you !

Comment: do you zip the dir for each request, or on a case by case bases?

Comment: on case by case, only when requested. But it's a huge cost of memory and time request for user

Comment: so maybe do it in the background, once a day, or what every frequency needed.

Comment: it's more live based, doing it once a day would be too restrictive. Currently I give to some users FTP access to their directories but it's really not ideal.

Comment: once an hour? sounds like you have not chosen the best hosting package for this project. If you don't have the cpu\ram for what you need upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Gzip is going to give you better compression, on average, than zip, but I would stick with zip because of its portability (Windows only supports this one).

[How to [recursively] Zip a directory in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php)

[Which is More Efficient: Zipping With a System Command or Using PHP ZipArchive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079674/which-is-more-efficient-zipping-with-a-system-command-or-using-php-ziparchive)

Comment: I know how to Zip, it's not the problem I'm doing it at the moment but it's too slow on huge directories. Any other ideas ?

Comment: If your users are Linux users, you could use tar + gzip. If they have 7zip, you could use that. You could also call the zip command directly from the command line (check edited post)

Comment: Ok so no miracles, going to use it through CLI and use a minimum compression. Thx !